# Wifi Direct - GO receives connection request

Tags: wifi-direct

I have 2 P2P devices (android smartphones). They created  a Wifi Direct Group. So, we have a Group owner and a Client. A third device appears, and wants to join the group sending a connection request to the GO. When this happens the GO BroadcastReceiver detects a disconnect. I would like to know if that is a normal behavior or I'm doing something wrong.

This is part of my BroadcastReceiver

```
else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION
                .equals(action)) {

            if (manager == null) {
                return;
            }

            NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            WifiP2pInfo wifiP2pInfo = (WifiP2pInfo) intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_INFO);
            WifiP2pGroup wifiP2pGroup = (WifiP2pGroup) intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_GROUP);



            if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                // we are connected with the other device, request connection
                // info to find group owner IP

            } else {
                // It's a disconnect            
            }
        } else if ....
```

Comment: I don''t know if this is documented anywhere, but indeed that is what I have also seen happening. Not remembering whether I could get any better solution for it, but as you will then get a new connected event, you could use timers to determine that whether it was a real disconnection, or just a new connection coming in,

Comment: May you explain me better about the use of those timers please?

Comment: Basically, if you are getting the disconnection event while actually getting a new connection. Then you get the connected event after it. Thus you could start a timer, and cancel it once you get connected event. Thus if your timer expires, it was not cancelled, thus the disconnected event was actual disconnection event.

Comment: I've been trying to do what you said but I have not been able to get the desired behavior. do you mind giving me a hand with a sketch of the code?

Comment: That's a very annoying case indeed... did you manage to find a working workaround?